# how can i operate onBlur event in react-native?

Tags: react-native, onblur

I'm trying to develop a search app using expo react-natvie.

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="placeholder"
  onBlur={() => console.log('blur')}
  onFocus={() => console.log('focus')}
/>
```

in this code, onFocus is working.
but, onBlur is not working.

i think "i clicked other text, so onBlur event will work"
but, still focus.

how can i operate onBlur event?

---

i add my code

```
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, height: 1000, backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      <TextInput
        onBlur={() => console.log('blur1')}
        onEndEditing={() => console.log('blur2')}
        onFocus={() => console.log('focus')}
        style={{ marginTop: 40, borderWidth: 1 }}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 600 }} onPress={() => console.log('press')} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

first, i clicked textinput. the onFocus event is work.
second, i clicked out. TouchableOpacity onPress event is work, but Textinput onBlur is not work...

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the onEndEditing prop on the TextInput component.

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="placeholder"
  onEndEditing={() => console.log('blur')}
  onFocus={() => console.log('focus')}
/>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. i'm too late. sorry.
But it didn't work as I thought.
i want to any action when onBlur event... but, it's hard to me

Comment: i add my code in content. could you look at the content one more time?

Comment: I found a solution.
when other content clicked, Keyboard.dismiss() method is operate textinput's onBlur event.